# UIBarButton initWithTitle

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a split view app.  In portrait mode, the menu would disappear after it was clicked.  To fix this I have added a new button, which is just supposed to display the menu:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // FORM LIST button was dissapearing, this adds it back everytime
    UIBarButtonItem *btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forms List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnMenu;

}
```

Which appears every time I load that view up.  My problem is that I am getting an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController showMenu:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d58810
```

I am pretty certain that the problem is with this line:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forms List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu:)];
```

My questions are:
(1) Is showMenu: the appropriate method?
(2) What is the target supposed to be?

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that you somewhere call showMenu: on a DetailViewController but this DetailViewController has no showMenu: method

Comment: I dont explicitly call showMenu anywhere else.  I thought it was a built in method?  I am a little bit confused about how my menu is displayed in the first place

Comment: If you have no showMenu: method you found your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you I have found multiple problems with my code.

(1)  I thought showMenu was a built in function, and do not had it declared anywhere in my program.

(2)  I did not know how the target or action worked.

Thanks guys (girls?) !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your method has an argument

```
- (void)showMenu:(id)sender
- (IBAction)showMenu:(id)sender
```

If it has no arguments, so if it is just `-(void)showMenu` , then you should remove the `:` (colon) from `@selector(showMenu:)`.

When you call the `showMenu` from your actual view (i.e, the `Main View`), the showMenu method is supposed to be declared somewhere in your `Main View`.